# How to make one finger move a Google Map but *not* two fingers

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, mobile, touch

I am taking my first steps into developing webapps specifically for mobile, and it's only going okay-ish so far.

I created a function that uses a two-finger swipe up or down to reorder the z-indices of two layers of content-- a dynamic Google Map and a content overlay. I want the map to be draggable with one finger when it is on top, but I need it not to move at all when the user is making the two-finger reordering gesture. I'm currently using `gestureHandling: 'greedy'`, which lets the user move the map with one finger, but does not disable two-finger movement.

I can't seem to find any way to do this in the Maps documentation-- is it simply not possible?